# New to Pygame, trying to rotate a png image but it it freezing the window

Tags: python-3.x, rotation, pygame

This is my program ive been working on with pygame, its a snake-like game where you collect apples to extend your snake and gain score, simple. But my problem atm is i am trying rotate my .png file snake head so it rotates with the snake as it moves, but whenever i try to the window freezes. The code that is freezing the window is just one extra line of code on (python) line 112, the line of code is simply:

```
return direction
```

This is the working code below:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

img_snake_head = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/School Stuff/Programs/Python Programs/Large Projects & Home Projects/Snake Pygame/snake_head.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
direction = "right"

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 45)

def snake(block_size, snakelist):
    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img_snake_head, 270)
    if direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img_snake_head, 90)
    if direction == "up":
        head = img_snake_head
    if direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img_snake_head, 180)

    gameDisplay.blit(img_snake_head, (snakelist[-1][0],snakelist[-1][1]))
    for XnY in snakelist[:-1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [XnY[0], XnY[1], block_size, block_size])

def message_to_screen(msg,colour):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2 - screen_text.get_width()/2, display_height/2 - screen_text.get_height()/2])

def gameLoop():
    global direction

    PlayerScore = 0

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    direction = "left"
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0                
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    direction = "right"
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0                
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    direction = "up"
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    direction = "down"
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
#This is where the 'return direction' goes, as i mentioned which was the code freezing the window...


        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x <= 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y <= 0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(blue)

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,AppleThickness,AppleThickness])

        snakehead = []
        snakehead.append(lead_x)
        snakehead.append(lead_y)
        snakelist.append(snakehead)
        snake(block_size, snakelist)

        if len(snakelist) > snakelength:
            del snakelist[0]

        if snakeMoving == True:
            if snakehead in snakelist[:-1]:
                gameOver = True

        snake(block_size, snakelist)

        scoretext = font.render("Score: "+str(PlayerScore), 0, (10,10,10))
        gameDisplay.blit(scoretext, (5, 10))

        pygame.display.update()

        if lead_x >= randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + AppleThickness or lead_x + block_size > randAppleX and lead_x + block_size < randAppleX + AppleThickness:
            if lead_y >= randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + AppleThickness or lead_y + block_size > randAppleY and lead_y + block_size < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
                randAppleX = round(random.randrange(10, display_width-AppleThickness)/10.0)*10.0
                randAppleY = round(random.randrange(10, display_height-AppleThickness)/10.0)*10.0
                snakelength += 1
                PlayerScore += 10

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

I hope someone can tell me why this is freezing as soon as possible! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return direction` isn't in the code you've provided. Also, try to post [mcve].

Comment: Yes ik return direction is not in there because that is what makes the window freeze, second of all i can't exactly post less because people are going to need to be able to run this exact code and find the problem to see what is freezing it.

Comment: If the line is what causing the error it should be included. Btw, do you need that line? Does it work otherwise? Also, you could remove the color constants for example since they're not what's providing to the problem. Try to remove as much as possible. You have hundreds of lines of code, which isn't a breeze to read through, so any effort in reducing the problem is increasing the chances of getting help. Also, following the PEP8 naming conventions makes it easier for other programmer to read your code. Naming variables and functions with `lowercase_and_underscore` and classes with `CamelCase`

Comment: Ok let me trya nd clean this up a bit

Comment: I looked at line 112 and it's just after you're handling the events in the `game_loop` function, right?. When you say it freezes do you mean the program terminates? A `return` statement exits the function it's located in, so a `return` statement in your `game_loop` function will end the program.

Comment: well no it is "freezing" the window as in the program stops running but the window stays open and the GUI stays visible

Comment: and you may be right about the return statement see i thought that the statement would return the 'direction' variable that was being re-assigned  within the for loop so the 'snake' function could then use it to rotate the image...

Comment: Okay, that's weird. It should just terminate the program unless there's more code after the code you've provided? Since direction is a global variable it will be changed everywhere when you reassign it. So it should work perfectly fine as it is unless there's something else causing problems.

Comment: Thats why i put global there to do what you just mentioned but it did not change a thing so thats why i thought i should add return

Comment: Okay so maybe my question should be why isn't my variable being updated properly and used by my snake function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you assigned the rotated image to a variable `head` but blitted `img_snake_head`. In your `snake` function change:

```
gameDisplay.blit(img_snake_head, (snakelist[-1][0],snakelist[-1][1]))
```

to

```
gameDisplay.blit(head, (snakelist[-1][0],snakelist[-1][1]))
```

and it should fix the problem.